# Why do I keep getting errors while trying to install MUI packages

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, npm-install

I'm trying to install MUI libraries however I keep getting these errors:

Here is what I've tried:

1. `npm install --force`
2. `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

````
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: filmpire_jsm@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^11.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.3.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!       @testing-library/react@"^11.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     react-dom@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@mui/material)
npm ERR!   5 more (the root project, @emotion/react, @emotion/styled, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @mui/styles@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.10.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/styles
npm ERR!     @mui/styles@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/samiennaciri/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/samiennaciri/.npm/_logs/2022-08-26T02_57_25_208Z-debug-0.log```
````

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file, then run `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`